# calculate distance of multi type data points

Tags: matlab, similarity, knn

I want to classify a data set via KNN method in Matlab but I have problem in calculating the distance of data points which have different data types.

Each point in my data set has various features with numeric and string types something like `X{Size,Lenght,Age,Coating,PipeType,Location}`
The first three features have numeric and second three have string (one or two words) values.

If I map string features to the binary codes for example for Coating values include `{Concrete encased,Gunite,Tar Coating,Poliken Coating}` if I consider two bits `{00,01,10,11}`
Is it logical if I calculate the distance of X and Y like this:

```
X:{Size,Lenght,Age,Coating,PipeType,Location}
Y:{Size,Lenght,Age,Coating,PipeType,Location}

Distance= Euclidean Distance (X,Y) on {Size,Lenght,Age} 
            + Hamming Distance (X,Y) on {Coating}
            + Hamming Distance (X,Y) on {PipeType}
            + Hamming Distance (X,Y) on {Location}
```

or

```
Distance= Euclidean Distance (X,Y) on {Size,Lenght,Age} 
          + {1 if a x and y have similar coating values and 0 otherwise}
          + ...
```

I really appreciate your suggestions.
Suggested articles and documents in this area would be useful as well.

Thanks
Mahsa

Answer (score 0):

For binary vectors, the Hamming distance and the Euclidean distance are actually the same.
So, you can convert `'Coating'` feature into a binary **vector** of length 4:

```
coating_vec( ii ) == 1 iff instance_coating == Coating_type{ii}
```

That is, for an instance with coating value "Tar" (the third possible Coating value) the binary feature vector for coating would be `[0 0 1 0]`.

Doing the same for `PipeType` and `Location`, you'll endup with a feature vector of length `3 + 4 + numPossible(PipeType) + numPossible(Location)`. Taking the Euslidean distance between these combined feature vectors should do the trick for you.